# How do I make CSS "transform: rotate" that does not displace an object in an svg file

Tags: css, svg

I have a circle in an svg file that needs to fill in based on a state (0-100%). I can't seem to rotate the circle (so it starts filling in from the correct position) without displacing it.

For now, I have played with some examples to get a circle that fills in from 0 - 100% over 10 seconds using this css.

```
.circle_percent_hide {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #323232;
  stroke-width: 6px;
  stroke-dasharray: 471;
  stroke-dashoffset: 471;
  animation: circle-length 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes circle-length {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 471;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

[image: It works]

It mostly works (starts a bit prematurely).

But it has to start from the other side. From what I could find, that could be done with `transform: rotate(180deg);`. But it seems to displace the object. I thought it was supposed to rotate around the center of the object?

I can move it with transform-origin, e.g., `transform-origin: center;`, but that's of course the center of the file/page, and not useful.

[image]

But I can't get it to line up nicely.

The circle in my svg file is:

```
    <circle
       r="29.364691"
       cy="-129.45181"
       cx="269.50244"
       id="test_circle"
       inkscape:export-filename="/Users/mfd356/all-floors.png"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="300"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="300"/>
```

How to I make the svg circle rotate 180° so the "filling" starts from the left hand side, without moving the circle in respect to the rest of the svg file?

Note: This will not be used with any html on my part, so any answer about that is unfortunately not a possibility. However, the implementation does take javascript (to set css class off svg objects) if that helps.

Comment: try adding the CSS property transform-box: fill-box (as well as transform-origin). Note transform-box does not work as an attribute unlike most other CSS in SVG.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Make it an answer, and I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks!